# Resizing images for mobile - everything works but images won't center

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am resizing images at 66% and everything looks great except they are left aligned. I used this code in the CSS

```
/*cells smaller for mobile*/
@media screen
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.cell-large{
max-width: 66%;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
}
```

And added this to the inline styling for each element for good measure,

```
padding-top: .25cm; display: inline-block; text-align: center;
```

But they are all still left aligned. What am I overlooking? It's the honeycomb cells with team member photos on [this page](http://inboundmarketing.digitalhive.buzz/home).

Thanks,
Rebekah

Answer (score 0):

Disregard - I applied text-align: center; to a higher level container and that seems to have done the trick. Not sure why, but oh well.

Comment: probably because inline and inline-block elements follow the text align of their parent